# How to update viewpager with new content using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have an app, it developed in Kotlin.One of my activity contain Tab layout with viewpager(e.g send ad receive).In Send tab contains data like A,B,C. In Receive tab 1,2,3. All the data from database. i want to update my viewpaer/tabview with new data(like D,E,F .. an 4,5,6.....).
i tries few methods but does not work.

> Note: I dont want to refresh the tablayout with old data because it works. i need only how to bind new data.when i close the app and open again it will update with new data but it does not work without close app.

```
private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection) {

            if (incoming.equals(OUTGOING)) {
                adapter.addFragment(SendingFragment(it!!, appDatabase, OUTGOING, networkDefinitionProvider), "SEND")
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //KK
            } else if (incoming.equals(INCOMING)) {
                adapter.addFragment(ReceiveFragment(it!!, appDatabase, INCOMING, networkDefinitionProvider), "RECEIVE")
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //KK
            }

            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

                override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                }

                override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

                }
                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {


                }

            })

            viewPager.adapter = adapter
    }


    inner class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager) {
        private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
        private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return mFragmentList[position]
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return mFragmentList.size
        }

        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment)
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
            return mFragmentTitleList[position]
        }

        override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
            return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
        }
    }
```

UPDATE :

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

            if(this.count < 3) {
                mFragmentList.add(ReceiveFragment(mfragmentIT, mfragmentAB, mfragmentINC, mfragmentnetwork))
                mFragmentList.add(SendingFragment(mfragmentIT, mfragmentAB, mfragmentINC, mfragmentnetwork))
                for (i in 1..3) {
                    println(i)
                }
            }
            return mFragmentList.get(i)
        }
```

UPDATE 2:

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            if (position == 0) {
                val tab1 = this.addFragment(com.crypto.wallet.activities.ReceiveFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork), "RECEIVE")
                return tab1 as Fragment
            } else {
                val tab2 = this.addFragment(com.crypto.wallet.activities.SendingFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork), "SEND")
                return tab2 as Fragment
            }
        }
```

Comment: FYI, you should not keep any instance of your fragments anywhere because it's the adapters duty to create and manage them.

Comment: okay but i dont have any instance in my fragment

Comment: I mean you should create fragments inside `getItem` method of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: okay but i need to pass the some of args through fragment so i dont have that values inside the `getItem`

Comment: it should be something like this: https://gist.github.com/mostafa-hz/dc006f55ed2d31acfb2114852f26294b

Comment: okay now i can pass like this,  override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment { ReceiveFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork)
        }

Comment: how to return more then one fragment

Comment: I've updated the gist, take a look again

Comment: it does not work

Comment: i get the error when i implement the gis of your code

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: no errorr it does not  work .  check my update code

Comment: dude, I think `addFragment` is returning `Unit`, just simply return `ReceiveFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork)` inside `if else`

Comment: bro,
Ihave tried this alredy as per you said

if (position == 0) {
                val tab1 = ReceiveFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork)
                return tab1
            } else {
                val tab2 = SendingFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork)
                return tab2
            }
            
            it shows only one tab (sometimes first tab, some times secound tab )

Comment: in that case `getCount` should return 2

Comment: okay i tried this but TABs not show

Comment: any other way? to fix this

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1, found: 3 Pager id: com.crypto.wallet:id/viewpager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.crypto.wallet.activities.MainActivity$ViewPagerAdapter